# TranslatableText inside a LiteralText SendMessage

Tags: java, minecraft-fabric

I want to program an item that posts the coordinates of certain ores in the chat.

But now my question is whether I can also put parts of the chat message as a translation or only hardcoded, so that it only outputs what I programmed.

I work with Minecraft fabric for 1.18.2 and the code below is what i have:

```
    private void outputValuableCoordinates(BlockPos blockPos, PlayerEntity player, Block blockBelow) {
        player.sendMessage(new LiteralText("Found "
                + blockBelow.asItem().getName().getString()
                + " at " +
                "(" + blockPos.getX() + ", " + blockPos.getY() + "," + blockPos.getZ() + ")"), false);
    }
```

And i would make a TranslatableText out of "Found" and "at"

Comment: Yes, you can allow for multiple translations. The typical way is to have a config file with all the translations, and you load that when the mod starts, and call a method that returns the correct one based on the system Local or the client language, for example, if you created a class called `Localisation` with a static method that gets the correct answer `getFoundText()` that returns the correct language then just replace `"found"` directly with `Localisation.getFoundText()`. You could also hard code multiple languages and do exactly the same thing with a getter method.

Comment: I would create a Manager that can get a message with an identifier like "found.item" and replace placeholders with what you need